# Fluent NHibernate Reference in one direction only?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to figure out how to get NHibernate to work with 1 to many and many to 1 type relationships.  I have the following setup, however it doesn't seem to work

```
public class Product {
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string SKU {get;set;}
     public decimal MSRP {get;set;}
}

public class Order {
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
     public IList<OrderLine> Lines {get;set;}
}

public class OrderLine {
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public Product Product {get;set;}
     public int Qty {get;set;}
     public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
     Id(x => x.Id);

     Map(x => x.Name);
     Map(x => x.SKU);
     Map(x => x.MSRP);
}

public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
     Id(x => x.Id);

     Map(x => x.CreatedOn);

     // This doesn't seem to work as I get an error that OrderLine is not mapped
     HasMany(x => x.Lines);
}

public class OrderLineMap : ClassMap<OrderLine>
{
     Id(x => x.Id);

     Map(x => x.Qty);
     Map(x => x.Price);

     // This doesn't seem to work as I get an error the Product isn't mapped         
     // An association from the table OrderLine refers to an unmapped class: Product
     References(x => x.Product);
}

public static class NHibernateUtils
{
    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer)
    {           
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(persistenceConfigurer)
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.FluentMappings.Add<ProductMap>();
                m.FluentMappings.Add<OrderLineMap>();
                m.FluentMappings.Add<OrderMap>();
            })
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Create(false, true))
            .BuildConfiguration()
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

So I am curious -- what am I doing wrong.  Note: I do NOT want to add the inverse properties to my objects.  So OrderLine should NOT need a reference to Order and Product should NOT need a reference to a collection of Orders.  Am I hitting a limitation? Or just missing something simple?

Comment: How are you registering your maps with the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: If you don't have a reference in code from OrderLine to Order you will still need a column in the database for it (or make it a many to many).  NHibernate can't guess the column if there isn't a mapping on the other side of a one to many, so you need to specify the column (eg. OrderId) using KeyColumn("OrderId")

Comment: Thanks, I can give that a try however I don't think that helps the main issue which is with the "References" concept -- it doesn't seem to have a way of setting a custom key colum

Comment: When you're adding the mappings, shouldn't the types be the map types. I.e. `ProductMap`, etc.?

Comment: good catch  - typeo in my example. I'll update it now

Comment: so I figured out part of the issue.  what was missing was the "PropertyRef".  Seems like that is required for this to work.  Now the issue I am running in to is when I go to save an object I get an error about "no persister" defined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the main issue -- I was missing the PropertyRef on the References() call.  Looks like this is required?  If so, should the exception be a bit more specific?